# EF Core dynamic Where expression builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am attempting to build a dynamic EF filtering system.

The query:

```
        var query = _db.Promotions.Select(x => new ListPromotionAdminResponseModel()
        {
            ActionUrl = x.ActionUrl,
            Approved = x.Approved,
            ForShop = x.Shop.Name,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Categories = x.Categories.Select(y => new CategoryResponseModel() { Id = y.CategoryId, Name = y.Category.Name })
        });
```

Attempts to enrich the IQueryable with the filter.

```
// Works as expected
query = query.Where(x => x.Name == "Name");

// Doesn't work
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ListPromotionAdminResponseModel), "x");
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(parameter, "Name"); ;
query = query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<ListPromotionAdminResponseModel
    , bool>>(Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant("test")), parameter));
```

However the dynamic expression does not evaluate es expected and returns the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Promotion>
.Join(
    outer: DbSet<Shop>, 
    inner: p => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p, "ShopId"), 
    outerKeySelector: s => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(s, "Id"), 
    innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Promotion, Shop>(
        Outer = o, 
        Inner = i
    ))
.Where(p => new ListPromotionAdminResponseModel{ 
    ActionUrl = p.Outer.ActionUrl, 
    Approved = p.Outer.Approved, 
    ForShop = p.Inner.Name, 
    Id = p.Outer.Id, 
    Name = p.Outer.Name, 
    Categories = DbSet<CategoryPromotion>
        .Where(c => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p.Outer, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p.Outer, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(c, "PromotionId"))
        .Join(
            outer: DbSet<Category>, 
            inner: c => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c, "CategoryId"), 
            outerKeySelector: c0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c0, "Id"), 
            innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new 
                TransparentIdentifier<CategoryPromotion, Category>(
                   Outer = o, 
                   Inner = i
            ))
        .Select(c => new CategoryResponseModel{ 
            Id = c.Outer.CategoryId, 
            Name = c.Inner.Name 
        }
        ) 
}
.Name == "test")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

End of Exception

The debug lambda tree of both statements is identical. What rookie mistake am I making here?

Comment: If you execute the part that is inside Where (the code that doesn't work) does not throw any exceptions?

Comment: The Exception is thrown when evaluating the 'doesn't work' where. The tree given in the description of the InvalidOperationException is generated by EF and invalid.  It appears that the expression is wrongly positioned.

Comment: So your question is in the middle box ? Why the Expression is not like `x.Name=="Name"` ? This part can not really be found at your exception, it just end's with `.Name == "test")'` could not be translated. This looks strange.
You construct that huge object ListPromotionAdminResponseModel and all you do is testing it's name, than you throw it away ? It's not stored or returned anywhere. I do not see any Where(x =>, where x is an ListPromotionAdminResponseModel. Maybe your Where(p=> should be an Select ?

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify that the third box is an exception in it's entirety. I simplly want to dynamically reproduce 'query = query.Where(x => x.Name == "Name");' Of course with different values, but for the sake of simplicity I have reduced the complexity of the query tot the bare minimum.

Comment: Can you not change the order of operations? Filter, force load, then get results, instead of (now) define results, filter, then load. So change to `_db.Promotions.Where(expression).ToList().Select(x => new ListPromotionAdminResponseModel ...)`. With `ToList` being the key part.

Comment: This would not work since EF will not know which tables to fetch to get the required data since the select statement will navigate to other relaitons